# Model objects are not passed to jsps in Spring MVC - InternalResourceView - renderMergedOutputModel

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, tiles

I am using JstlView Spring Tiles in my project.

When i try to send **form:errors** from validator to jsp through controller,errors are not being dispayed in jsp

when i debug,

1)errors are being printed in controller class before returning modelandview , from validator class.

2)Then error are also being printed in JstlView class from controller class.

So i think, requestDispatcher.forward(request, response) in jstlview class is not returning  model data to jsp.

Because when i tried HttpServletRequest or HttpServletResponse objects to retrive errors in jsp , values are being dispalyed in jsp.

Can some one help me in this used.

**How can i send model data to jsp renderMergedOutputModel- RequestDispatcher , redirect method.**

My code is as follows,

JstlView class:

```
public class JstlView extends InternalResourceView {

 @Override
 protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

 // Determine the path for the request dispatcher.
 String dispatcherPath = prepareForRendering(request, response);

 // set original view being asked for as a request parameter
 request.setAttribute("partial", dispatcherPath.substring(dispatcherPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));

// force everything to be template.jsp
 RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp");
 requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);

 System.out.println("**********************"+model.get("userName"));
 }

}
```

## Servlet.xml

```
<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="viewClass" value="com.tms.web.view.JstlView" />

    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />

    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Controller:

```
 private LoginValidator loginValidator;
     @Autowired
     public void setUserValidator(LoginValidator loginValidator) {
         this.loginValidator = loginValidator;
     }

       final RequestHandler  requestHandler = new RequestHandler();
       @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public ModelAndView login() {
          return new ModelAndView("login", "users", new users());
       }

   @RequestMapping(value = "/logins",method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView validateUser(@Valid users user, BindingResult result,@ModelAttribute("users")users users,ModelMap model,RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,HttpServletRequest req) 
   {
       this.loginValidator.validate(user, result);
            if (result.hasErrors()) 
            {
                  model.putAll(result.getModel());//values not retuned to jsp
                  req.setAttribute("userName", result.getFieldError().getDefaultMessage().toString());  //working fine values retuned to jsp
                  return new ModelAndView("/login", model);
            }
           else
           {
                    //succes related code
                    return new ModelAndView(redirect, model);
           }    
      }
```

Validator

```
@Component
public class LoginValidator implements Validator {

  @Override
  public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {

    return clazz.isAssignableFrom(users.class);
  }
  @Override
  public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
    users user = (users) obj;
    String userName = user.getUserName();
    String password = user.getPassword();
    validateuserName(userName,password, errors);
  }

  private void validateuserName(String userName, String password,Errors errors) {
    if (!(isValidString(userName))) {
       errors.rejectValue("userName", "userName.required","Username should not be blank");
    }
    else if(!(isValidString(password)))
    {
        errors.rejectValue("password", "password.required","Password should not be blank");
    }
  }

  private boolean isValidString(String str) {
    return isNotNull(str) && (str.length() > 0 ) && !(str.isEmpty());
  }

  private boolean isNotNull(String str) {
    return str != null;
  }
}
```

Jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" %>
<%@ page isScriptingEnabled="true" isELIgnored="false" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>



    <form:form method="POST" action="/TMSWeb/logins"  commandName="users" modelAttribute="users">                                          
                                <input name="password" type="password" align="center"/> 
                                <form:errors path="password" cssClass="error" element="div" /> 
                                <input type="submit" class="buttonorange"  value="Login"/>
            </form:form>
```

In Spring MVC when I can access my beans in JSP without JstlView's, then, in my JSP I can write (${errors). But when the same JSP is a part of a tiles view, these properties aren't accessible.

Can someone help me in this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are extending the class **org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView** in your **JstlView**  class and override **renderMergedOutputModel**  method, where you are missing to expose the model object. call this method **exposeModelAsRequestAttributes(model, requestToExpose);** from override method as shown below. Try with below code, which is worked for me.

```
@Override
protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest    request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

// Expose the model object as request attributes.
     exposeModelAsRequestAttributes(model,request);

// Determine the path for the request dispatcher.
String dispatcherPath = prepareForRendering(request, response);

// set original view being asked for as a request parameter
request.setAttribute("partial", dispatcherPath.substring(dispatcherPath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1));

// force everything to be template.jsp
RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/template.jsp");
requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);

System.out.println("**********************"+model.get("userName"));
}

}
```

Comment: This post is 3 year old, but it solved a problem which I've been fighting over for more than a month! Up Up!